# What is Aunt Muriel's maiden name?

Tags: harry-potter

We know Ron Weasley had a great-aunt named Muriel. However, this was on his mother's side, so they wouldn't share a name. If Muriel is related to Molly on her father's side, she could be Muriel Prewett, but we don't know if she is. Is anything known on the topic?

Answer (score 2):

We don't know:

> Her surname is unknown. It may be Prewett, but only if she is related to Molly on her father's side.
>
> *- [Muriel - Harry Potter Wikia](http://harrypotter.wikia.com/wiki/Muriel)*

There's also no reference to her surname on Pottermore.

> Surname possibly Prewett? As Molly's aunt, Muriel could be either the sister or the sister-in-law of Molly's parents. Even if Muriel is a connection through Molly's father, a Prewett, that doesn't necessarily mean that Muriel's adult surname was Prewett. The only thing that is certain is that Muriel is not a Weasley.
>
> *- [Auntie Muriel - HP-Lexicon](https://www.hp-lexicon.org/character/weasley-family/auntie-muriel/)*

Heres another quote that enforces the fact that we can't be sure of her Surname

> Ron's Auntie Muriel (no mention whether she's a Weasley or a Prewett, though her opinions suggest she is a Prewett) is an aged, outspoken, eccentric relative of the Weasley family.
>
> *- [Auntie Muriel - Wikibooks.org](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Muggles%27_Guide_to_Harry_Potter/Characters/Auntie_Muriel)*